# Combobox crashes when selecting item with keyboard

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a problem with the code below, basically what is does is read from a path where files with extension .config are stored, it reads the names of the files without extension and displays them all in a combobox.  That works fine and if you click on the down arrow and select a name it actually does what it's supposed to, however, once I have selected an item from the dropdown with the mouse and I go back and start typing inside the combobox my application crashes throwing a  exception.

I've tried adding a try-catch-finally but it keeps throwing the same error.  Could it be the loop that is causing my application to crash once I start typing in the combobox?

p.d.  If I just use the mouse to select an item from the dropdown menu my application works fine but once I've selected an item with the mouse and use the keyboard to type another item name inside the combobox my app crashes.  Any pointers would be helpful.

```
// Gets all the file names from the path assigned to templatePath 
// and assigns it to the string array fname
string[] fname = Directory.GetFiles(templatePath); 

// Begin sorting through the file names assigned to the string array fname
foreach (string file in fname)
{
    // Remove the extension from the file names and compare the list with 
    // the dropdown selected item
    if (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) == cbTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        // StreamReader gets the contents from the found file and assigns
        // them to the labels
        using (var obj = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file)))
        {
            lbl1.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl2.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl3.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl4.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl5.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl6.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl7.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl8.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl9.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            lbl10.Content = obj.ReadLine();
            obj.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exception details that you are getting.

Comment: You should handle the case when the file is not exactly 10 lines. You don't need to call dispose on `obj`, because `using` does this. Can you add the code that uses the combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is this is probably causing the error:

```
cbTemplates.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

When you start typing in the combobox, the SelectedItem becomes null.

You should test whether the `cbTemplates.SelectedItem` is null before attempting to invoke `ToString()` on it. And if you're trying to match on the text of the combo-box, you might try using `cbTemplates.Text` instead.

And as others commented on your question, you don't need to call `Dispose` inside `using` and you should consider the possibility that the file might not contain 10 lines..

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you, I did what you suggested (validate if the combobox is null) and it worked just fine, I left the .ToString() though because .Text was misreading my files.  Anyway, even with .ToString() when you validate apparently your app doesn't crash, it just moves on.  Thanks again!!! ( if (cbTemplates.SelectedItem != null))